# Pandas - how to check if an item in a column is below a certain value and if so remove this and any associated rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: 'age' and 'name'. Which looks like this (when opened in notepad):

```
,age,name
0,18,Bill
1,22,Harry
2,9,Bill
4,20,William
```

(the first column is an index)

I want to drop any rows where the age in the age column is below a certain a value e.g. 10. And to do this I can do this (which works):

```
df = df[df['age'] > 1
```

However, I also want to drop the rows which have the same name in the name column. For example in the above snippet of my data frame I would want the output to look like this:

```
,age,name
1,22,Harry
4,20,William
```

So far I have this:

```
df = (df[df['age'] > 10).groupby(df['name']).transform('any')]
```

This piece of code is invalid syntax. This is a similar question to one I asked before so am confused why the above code doesn't work.

Any help would be great

Comment: Fun with pandas.  So many ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `all`

```
df[df.age.gt(10).groupby(df.name).transform('all')]
Out[338]: 
   Unnamed: 0  age     name
1           1   22    Harry
3           4   20  William
```

Comment: What does gt mean? greater than?

Comment: @HarryMaguire yes

Answer (score 3):

You could also start by dropping duplicates in the name column, and then indexing for age greater than 10:

```
df.drop_duplicates('name',keep=False)[df.age > 10]

   age     name
1   22    Harry
4   20  William
```

**Edit** Based on the question title and the comments, maybe I misinterpreted the question and in fact you are just trying to remove all names in your dataframe that have at least one value below 10. In this case, you could do something like this:

```
df[~df.name.isin(df.loc[df.age < 10, 'name'])]

   age     name
1   22    Harry
4   20  William
```

Comment: I guess the question was to remove only the names for which at least one of the values in the age column is < 10. Your code would remove all name duplicates. Did I understand it right?

Comment: Hmm, that's not how I interpreted it, but you could be right... not sure. If OP clarifies, I'll delete or edit this answer

Comment: Even I didn't interpret that way from the question. But the question title indicates so I guess.

Comment: Well, in any case, I just posted another solution as an edit that might satisfy a different interpretation to the question...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` with `filter`:

```
df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: all(x.age > 10)).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   i  age     name
0  1   22    Harry
1  4   20  William
```